# function is not an element of std

Tags: c++

I got some quite strange errors compiling code under gcc. It tells me that `std::function` does not exist.

I can recreate the error with the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>

void test(){ printf ("test"); }

int main() {
    std::function<void()> f;
    f = test;
    f();
}
```

If I run gcc (from cygwin): (my error message was German, so i translated it. It may be sound different on a English gcc)

```
$ gcc test.cpp
test.cpp: in function "int main(): 
test.cpp:7:3: Error: "function" is not an element of "std"« 
test.cpp:7:25: Error: "f" was not defined in this scope
```

With MSVC it compiled successfully. 
Please tell me what I am doing wrong in my code.

Johannes

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11?

Comment: no, if i do ´gcc -std=c++0x test.cpp´ it throws a bunch of linker errors i could not understand

Comment: You need `g++`, not `gcc`, see answers below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Compile it as:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x
```

`-std=c++0x` is needed because you're using C++11 features, otherwise `g++ test.cpp` is enough.

Make sure you've latest version of GCC. You can check the version as:

```
g++ --version
```

Comment: "If you use gcc test.cpp, then it assumes C program!" Not true. gcc infers the language from the file extension. If it assumed a C program, the error message would be quite different. `std::function` would be a syntax error in C. It wouldn't produce a message about `function` not existing in the `std` namespace. What is true is that `gcc` (unlike `g++`) doesn't automatically link against the c++ standard library, so you'd get linker errors if you don't specify the appropriate -l flag manually.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile in `C++` mode, and in `C++11` mode. So you need `g++` and the `-std` flag set to `c++0x`.

> g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x

You can also use `-std=c++11` from gcc 4.7 onwards.