# How to set Netbeans to use C++11?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am a beginner in C++ as well as a beginning Netbeans user. How would I configure Netbeans to use C++11? I cannot seem to find the option anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

right click on your project -> Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> Basic Options/C Standard -> C++11

Adding `-std=c++11` compiler switch is also possible there, under Compilation Line -> Additional Options.

Note that you need appropriately new NetBeans version to have C++11 support.

Further reading:

[Setting Default NetBeans Options (-std=c99, -Wall) for C programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882981/setting-default-netbeans-options-std-c99-wall)

[NetBeans settings for GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114042/netbeans-settings-for-gcc/11643274)

Comment: This did the trick. Since C++98 was the default, do you know how I can set C++11 as the default for all future projects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882981/setting-default-netbeans-options-std-c99-wall http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114042/netbeans-settings-for-gcc/11643274

Comment: Haha, those answers seem really improvised. Anyways, I heard jetbrains is rolling out a C++ ide,so maybe that is more polished than netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

regardless of IDE you setup this by specifying a compiler option.

for example if you use gcc compiler you would set a compiler option like so:
`g++ -std=c++11`

and of course add other options you want.

see this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882981/setting-default-netbeans-options-std-c99-wall)

Answer (score 1):

Right click Project->Properties->Buld->C++ Compiler->Basic Options->C++ Standard

Note that using C++11 won't work though unless you have G++ 4.7 or later, which is not on a debian package yet. 
So, you can either build the newest version of G++ (4.7.4) or set the compilation line->Addition options to "-std=c++0x", which is the same as the C++11 according to this post:

[function is not an element of std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018300/function-is-not-an-element-of-std)

Comment: I use debian and debian's gcc packackage is 4.7 version. so it's possible to use c++11.