# c++ unable to resolve identifier to_string

Tags: c++, netbeans

Good day

I have searched high and low, yet no solution.

**IDE:** NetBeans IDE 8.2 
**MinGW:** Using the "latest" MinGW compiler.

**Original Issue:**

I would like to convert an int to string.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c) method, I attempted to convert to string, however

this proposed method `std::to_string()` results in the error when used(with the to_string as the error)

> unable to resolve identifier to_string

Project dependancies:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

Searching for a solution to this issue, 2 promonent solutions appeared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686264/erroneous-unable-to-resolve-identifier-in-netbeans)

Setting the C and C++ compiler versions should apparenlty solve this issue.

It did not, any suggestions?

**Minimal Code:**

```
#include <string>

struct User_VPN_Info{
    std::string name, expire;
    int DaysLeft;

    User_VPN_Info(){}

    User_VPN_Info(std::string _name, std::string _expire, int _DaysLeft){
        name = _name;
        expire = _expire;
        DaysLeft = _DaysLeft;
    }

    std::string getString(){
        return(name + " + " + expire + " + " + std::to_string(DaysLeft) + " ; ");                                                    
    }                                             //^_______^ problem here
};
```

Comment: `std::to_string` was added in C++11. Is there any chance NetBeans would be compiling with e.g. C++03? Is there a way to specify which version to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591936/how-to-set-netbeans-to-use-c11

Comment: You should pass `-std=c++11` as a compiler option.

Comment: @CoryKramer yes, I have the option of C++98, C++11, C++14. I have attempted using 11 and 14, reparsing the project after each change, still no luck

Comment: @SimonKraemer see above

Comment: @RalphTandetzky I am unsure where to add this, I check the project properties, Build>C++ Compiler. Here I have 5 options/settings. 1. Include Directories, 2. Include Headers, 3. Preprocessor Definitions, 4. Use Linker Libraries (check box), 5. C++ Standard, I selected C++11 now (options are c++98,11,14)

Comment: Please show your actual (minimal) code

Comment: @KGCybex Sometimes, build configurations do not get updated properly. Try to select C++11 or C++14 and then *rebuild* the whole project. With *rebuild* I don't mean just build but removing all created files before recompiling. When you select *build*, then it might not work properly, because the generated binaries appear to be up to date and don't get compiled again.

Comment: @Useless see post update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is know issue with MinGW

> ```
> gcc  -std=gnu++14 -Wall -Wextra  main.cpp
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:24:26: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
>      cout<<to_string(a)<<endl;
>
> gcc  --version
>
> gcc.exe (GCC) 5.3.0
> ```

Instant of 'standard" MinGw you should use MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows

> ```
> /mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin
> ./g++   -std=c++14   main.cpp
> ```

compile without errors

If you want change toolchain in Netbeans you have to add new Tool Collection in project properties.

Comment: thank you steff, after following your proposed solution, I have solved my problem, I unfortunately will not be marking this as the correct answer, although it did assist me and put me on the right path to solving the issue, I will post the solution will all the information, etc. but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer the question, I would like to thank steff for guiding me in the right direction, thus allowing me to solve the problem, please give his answer an upvote if you deem it worthy.

**My Installation Info**

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Java: 1.8.0_112; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.112-b15
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_112-b15
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_ZA (nb)
```

**Setting Up Netbeans, etc**

Orignally, I had install mingw32, as specified by the [netbeans documentation page for seting up netbeans with c++](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers_windows), this is to setup the compiler for c++ (since it appears not to do this automatically).

I follow all the steps, adding the path to the environment, and not changing any installation paths, to keep it as to the "tutorial" as possible.

After coding and importing code, I ran into the error mentioned above, and so steff suggested to use the MinGW64 compiler, where I had just used the mingw32 compiler.

**Solution**

Overview of steps taken (*my solution*)

1. Install MinGW64
2. Add toolchain (aka compiler)
3. Change project toolchain ( aka compiler)

**1.**

MinGW64 setup found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) from sourceforge

Install this, changing no settings ofcourse.

**2.**

Opening up netbeans > Tools > Options > C/C++ tab.

Here I have MinGW on the left, that is the pre installed compiler, which exists due to the installation instructions from the documentation page (the MinGW32 compiler/toochain which is giving the error)

Click Add (to add new compiler), browse to the location of the newly install MinGW64 compiler, mine is in:

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\
```

Name the compiler something appropriate, I named mine "MinGW_64" and for the Tool Collection Family, select the "GNU MinGW", and click ok.

- Now, adding the links to the compiler exe's.

In my case, I had to fill in 2 sections, namely the `C Compiler` field and the `C++ Compiler` field.

**Please note** I am unsure as to which specific exe the c++ fied should point to, I just selected the `c++.exe`, this compiler solved my problem, I am unsure of the `gcc.exe`

Please see image below as a reference.

[image]

After this is done, make the MinGW64 compiler your default compiler.

**3.**

Finally, if you have an open project in which this error occurs (which I assume is most probably the case), there is one last thing to do.

Right click on your project > Properties > Build.

Look for the option "Tool Collection", the corresponding compiler name should be "MinGW" (same name as that of the compiler I refered to earlier - the faulty one), this should be changed to the new MinGW_64 compiler you have just installed and added in the Tools > Options > C/C++ section.

**DONE!**

Close your project properties, the project should reparse automatically, if not, right click on project > Code Assistance > Reparse Project, wait for reparse and your problem *should* be solved.

I really hope this helps.