# Error coverting int to string C++

Tags: c++, string, int

I'm working on this code that takes a numeric string and fills an array with each "digit" of the string.  The issue I'm having is trying to convert an integer to a string.  I tried using to_string to no avail.

Here is the code (note this is pulled from a larger program with other functions):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> 
#include <typeinfo>

    int fillarr(int &length) {
        int arr[length];
        string test = "10010"; //test is an example of a numeric string
        int x = 25 + ( std::rand() % ( 10000 - 100 + 1 ) );

        std::string xstr = std::to_string(x); //unable to resolve identifier to_string
        cout << xstr << endl;
        cout << typeid (xstr).name() << endl; //just used to verify type change

        length = test.length(); //using var test to play with the function
        int size = (int) length;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
            char c = test[i];
            cout << c << endl;
            arr[int(i)] = atoi(&c);

        }
        return *arr;
    }
```

How can I convert int x to a string?  I have this error: unable to resolve identifier to_string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c). You need to explain what went wrong with `std::to_string`, not just say "it didn't work"; we can't psychically debug your issues with the one obvious way to convert `int` to `std::string`.

Comment: I know it's similar, but I just don't know why I'm getting an error for what looks like a tried and true method.  I'm new to C++ so any tips are more than welcome.

Comment: The code won't compile and I left the error in the code as a comment

Comment: `std::to_string` is in <string> which is conspicuously absent from the list of includes. Could be part of your problem.

Comment: Is this your whole program? Do you have a `main` function?

Comment: I added in the <string> include and the same issue is present.

Comment: My main is just a function call to this function with a generic value for 'length'

Comment: Obviously a compiler with Variable Length Array support, so not Visual Studio, what Compiler and version?

Comment: [you shouldn't use `rand()` in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13445688/995714). And [don't use `atoi`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of netbeans with c++

Comment: Probably GCC then. Open a command prompt and type g++ -v to get the version.

Comment: `std::to_string` was added in C++11. C++ 11 isn't turned on by default in any GCC that's likely to ship with Netbeans. Probably 4.8 or 4.9. Anyone know how to turn on C++ 11 support in Netbeans?

Comment: Give this answer a shot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24591974/4581301

Comment: Hmm no luck so far.  I'll let you know if I come up with a solution.  Also thanks for the tips on some the other problems in my code.

Comment: also try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-g

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by user 4581301, you need an [`#include <string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to use string functions.

The following, though is wrong:

```
arr[int(i)] = atoi(&c);
```

The `atoi()` will possibly crash because `c` by itself is not a string and that mean there will be no null terminator.

You would have to use a buffer of 2 characters and make sure the second one is '\0'. Something like that:

```
char buf[2];
buf[1] = '\0';
for(...)
{
   buf[0] = test[i];
   ...
}
```

That being said, if your string is decimal (which is what `std::to_string()` generates) then you do not need `atoi()`. Instead you can calculate the digit value using a subtraction (much faster):

```
    arr[int(i)] = c - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I modified my code a bit per suggestion from everyone and ended up handling the conversion like this:

```
string String = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << x) )->str();
cout << String << endl;
```